# Dual graphics set up: NVIDIA and Intel, possible?

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, dual-graphics

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a system with an NVIDIA Geforce GTX 950 graphics card. I had no problems until I switched on the iGPU (Intel HD Graphics 4600) in the UEFI settings. I want to use the NVIDIA card for some CUDA computation and the integrated graphics to drive a monitor. I can set this up pretty easily with an AMD card because it doesn't require additional drivers. The NVIDIA driver seems to be interfering with my integrated graphics card and I end up with a login loop if I select my integrated graphics as the POST display.

I checked out `Bumblebee`, which doesn't seem related to my use case. I don't want to switch between the two graphics cards. I just want them to function like two separate independent graphics cards, like they would do on Windows.

Some additional information:

- `.xsession-errors` reports `extension "GLX" missing on display ":0"` after the failed logins.
- The `.Xauthority` file has the correct permission, and removing it does not resolve the issue.
- NVIDIA driver 352.93 is in use. The driver is actually working, as I can execute my CUDA job and use `nvidia-smi` from the TTYs. It just somehow screws up displays on the Intel graphics.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check out this Q&A and see if it helps with your NVIDIA problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics/

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to function the way they do in Windows then bumblebee really is your best bet.

The monitor will run on the intel chipset and whenever you want to run something with your nvidia card you use optirun or primus if primus is installed.

example: optirun steam

You can do this through the terminal or even add it to a shortcut/launcher